# Empty listView in listFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I have a list fragment. When I run the app, I see an empty `listView`.
I don't know what the problem is. Maybe I should use a library?

```
public class MyEmployeFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_ID = "p_id";
    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "p_name";
    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_LAST_NAME = "p_last_name";
    ArrayList<spr_item> ret_data;
    MyTask task;
    SimpleAdapter sAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        task = new MyTask();
        task.execute();

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_employe, null);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ret_data = new ArrayList<spr_item>();

        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
                ret_data.size());
        Map<String, Object> m;
        for (int i = 0; i < ret_data.size(); i++) {
            m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_ID, ret_data.get(i).getId());
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ret_data.get(i).getName());
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_LAST_NAME, ret_data.get(i).getLastName());
            data.add(m);
        }

        // массив имен атрибутов, из которых будут читаться данные
        String[] from = {ATTRIBUTE_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_LAST_NAME};
        // массив ID View-компонентов, в которые будут вставлять данные
        int[] to = {R.id.tw_employe_id, R.id.tw_employe_name, R.id.tw_employe_last_name};

        // создаем адаптер
         sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.list_item_employee,
                from, to);

            // определяем список и присваиваем ему адаптер
            ListView lvSimple = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            lvSimple.setAdapter(sAdapter);

    }

         class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

             @Override
             protected void onPreExecute() {
                 super.onPreExecute();

             }

             @Override
             protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                 String s = "5ACACEC6-752B-4EFF-AA50-EEBE58A52113";
                 // String user_guid = myPrefs.getString("guid", "");

                 HttpActivity _http = new HttpActivity("192.168.10.11", "80");
                 _http.set_addr_protocol("/WebSite/P/spr/spr.aspx/");
                 _http.add_param("query", "spr_employee_get");
                 // _http.add_param("p_guid", user_guid.toString().trim());
                 _http.add_param("p_guid", s);
                 _http.send();

                 List<spr_item> tempList = _http.getArrayParamValue();
                 for(int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++)
                     ret_data.add(tempList.get(i));

                 //employer_name = _http.getArrayParamValue("p_name");
                 //employer_id = _http.getArrayParamValue("p_id");
                 //employer_last_name = _http.getArrayParamValue("p_last_name");

                 return null;
             }

             protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                 super.onPostExecute(result);

                 sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

             }
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the above code apart from the Empty list you may have the null pointer exception too if the task is too quick to load. Here onCreate is called first onCreateView next and onActvityCreated next. So it is better to initialise adapter in onCreate set the adapter to listView in onCreateView and set listView listeners in onActvityCreated using getListView() method.

Apart from this if you are using local database to retrieve data you need to use cursorADapter to fetch the data

Comment: Im using the data from server. I get json response and put it into listVIew

Answer (score 0):

The adapter's data references (ArrayList, array, etc.), tend to get lost pretty easily. In that case the notfiyDataSetChanged() method will not work. If you are adamant on using this method I suggest you check the references to the adapter's source again. If that is not the case this is the approach I've used in my project. A small warning in advance, the formatting and the closing of brackets is poorly executed, but the approach is still clear enough.

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {

// For populating the list view.
SomeAdapter adapter;

public MyFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] parameters = {"url for request"};
    new GetRequestTask().execute(parameters);

}

// The async task to make the HTTP GET requests.
class GetRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("GetRequestTask", "Client protocol exception.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GetRequestTask", "IO exception.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Update UI with the new response.
    new UpdateUITask().execute(result);
        }
    }
}

// The async task to update the UI.
class UpdateUITask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Something>>{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Something> doInBackground(String... input) {
        ArrayList<Something> someArray = new ArrayList<Something>();
        try{
            // Do some JSON magic to parse the data.
        }
        catch(JSONException je){
            Log.e("UpdateUITask", "JSON parsing error occured.");
            je.printStackTrace();
        }

        return someArray;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Something> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("UpdateUITask", "Updating UI.");
        adapter = new SomeAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.some_list_item, restOfTheParameters);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}


    }
}
```